# Cutout section of CSS3 polygon, but retain contents?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have some code:

```css
:root {
 --main-color1: rgba(255,000,000,0.7);
 --main-colorB: rgba(000,000,000,0.3);
 
 --border-width: 5px;
 --arrow-width: 16px;
}

body {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
 font-size: 20px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

.full { width: 1280px; margin: 0 auto; }

.inline { display: inline-block; }
.inner { -webkit-clip-path: inset(var(--main-border) 0); }

.color1 { background-color: var(--main-color1); }
.colorB { background-color: var(--main-colorB); }

.match {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 min-width: 200px;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
  var(--arrow-width) 0,
  0 50%,
  var(--arrow-width) 100%,
  calc(100% - var(--arrow-width)) 100%,
  100% 50%,
  calc(100% - var(--arrow-width)) 0
 );
}
.match .inner {
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
  calc(var(--arrow-width) + var(--border-width)) var(--border-width),
  calc(var(--border-width) + 3px)  50%,
  calc(var(--arrow-width) + var(--border-width)) calc(100% - var(--border-width)),
  calc(100% - var(--border-width) - var(--arrow-width)) calc(100% - var(--border-width)),
  calc(100% - var(--border-width) - 3px) 50%,
  calc(100% - var(--border-width) - var(--arrow-width)) var(--border-width)
 );
}
```

```html
  <div class="match colorB inline">
   <div class="inner color1">
    <div class="title">Grand Finals</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, this is a grey CSS3 polygon, with a red CSS3 polygon inside of it, with text inside of that...

The problem I am having is both polygons have an alpha tranparency. Unfortunately, because the second polygon is inside of the first polygon, it alters the resulting colors of the second polygon. Is there a way I can cut out the area first polygon so that it doesn't alter the colors of the second polygon? While also retaining the transparency?

Comment: Where is `--main-border` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolutely positioned pseudo elements, and clip them to create the border, and rotate the bottom one. Because of the rotation, there is a small overlapping in with `::after` element, which I think you can fix by clipping in manually to the request path instead of rotating the top one.

```css
:root {
  --main-color1: rgba(255, 000, 000, 0.7);
  --main-colorB: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.3);
  --border-width: 5px;
  --arrow-width: 16px;
}
body {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.full {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
.inner {
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(var(--main-border) 0);
}
.color1 {
  background-color: var(--main-color1);
}

.match {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.match::before,
.match::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--main-colorB);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(var(--arrow-width) 0, 0 50%, calc(var(--border-width) + 4px) 50%, calc(var(--arrow-width) + var(--border-width) + 1px) var(--border-width), calc(100% - var(--arrow-width) - var(--border-width)) var(--border-width), calc(100% - var(--border-width) - 3px) 50%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--arrow-width)) 0);
    content: '';
}
  
  .match::before {
    }
  
  .match::after {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
.match .inner {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(calc(var(--arrow-width) + var(--border-width)) var(--border-width), calc(var(--border-width) + 3px) 50%, calc(var(--arrow-width) + var(--border-width)) calc(100% - var(--border-width)), calc(100% - var(--border-width) - var(--arrow-width)) calc(100% - var(--border-width)), calc(100% - var(--border-width) - 3px) 50%, calc(100% - var(--border-width) - var(--arrow-width)) var(--border-width));
}
```

```html
<div class="match inline">
  <div class="inner color1">
    <div class="title">Grand Finals</div>
  </div>
</div>
```